# JQuery Rotating Text

Tags: jquery, autorotate

I have some text that i need to rotate, this is what i have now:

```
> <div id="facts">
>         <blockquote class="fact visible">
>            xxx  
>         </blockquote>
>         <blockquote class="fact">
>            yyy
>         </blockquote>
>          <blockquote class="fact">
>             zzz
>         </blockquote>
>         <blockquote class="fact">
>            ooo
>         </blockquote>
>     </div>
```

and my jquery is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

$("div#facts").height(factMaxHeight);

    setTimeout("rotateSlide()",7000);      
});   
.............

$('blockquote.fact').each(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('visible')) {
            $(this).fadeOut(5000,function () { 
                $(this).removeClass('visible');
                $(this).next().setVis
            });
        }//if
        else {
            $(this).fadeIn(5000,function () {
                $(this).addClass('visible');
            });
        }
    }); 
    setTimeout("rotateSlide()",7000);
```

so...xxx show up fine, but then it rades out, i see all of the other 3, yyy,zzz and ooo overlayed on top of each other, it does not do it one by one, please help me figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to see the complete code, ie. the rotateSlide function. 
But from the looks of it you at least need to have a counter variable to work out which quote to show, and which one to show next.

Comment: Keeping a separate counter variable would just be asking for trouble. The `.visible` class already signifies which one is visible, and from that it's not at all difficult to figure out which one to show next by examining the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your jQuery each:

```
$('blockquote.fact').each(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('visible')) {
        $(this).fadeOut(5000,function () { 
            $(this).removeClass('visible');
            $(this).next().setVis
        });
        if($(this).next().size()) {
            $(this).next().fadeIn(5000,function () {
                $(this).addClass('visible');
            });
        } else {
            $(this).parent().children().first().fadeIn(5000,function () {
                $(this).addClass('visible');
            });
        }
        return false
    }
});
```

Comment: Whoops: the return true should be changed to a return false (for performance) or removed (for confusion reduction)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're iterating through all the facts at once. How about simply this:

```
$('blockquote.fact.visible').each(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(5000, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('visible');

        var next = $(this).next();
        if (next.length == 0)
            next = $('blockquote.fact:first'); // If we're at the end of the list, go back to the first one.

        next.addClass('visible').fadeIn(5000);
    });
});
setTimeout(rotateSlide, 7000);
```

As an aside, ***please*** don't use the hideous "rotateSlide()" notation for `setTimeout`. Just pass it the function you want to call, as shown above.